# How to call setter method on ${body} in a Camel route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have tried to set a property on the body of a Java bean constituting the message in transit through a Camel route. I have tried various approaches e.g.

```
    <route>
        ...
        ..
        <transform>
            <simple>${body.label} = ${property.label}</simple>
        </transform>
        ...
        ..
    </route>
```

in this particular case the `${body}` is a Java bean with a `setLabel(String label)` method and the `${property.label}` is set by other means in another route. In this example the result is not the desired (and I understand why), i.e. after the transform the body of the message is replaced with the `${body.label} = ${property.label}` string.

My current work-around is to manually code a transformer as a Spring bean and set the label property of the Java bean in code but I like to find out if there is a simpler/smarter way to achieve this, preferably in XML DSL which is what I use?

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible with `simple`, but you could do it using `groovy`:

```
<setBody>
    <groovy>request.body.label = exchange.getProperty('label')
            return request.body
    </groovy>
</setBody>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply. Your suggestion works but there is one side effect that ruins it for me and that is that the body of the message seems to be replaced with the value of the label property and I loose the bean in transit.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that it uses value of a last operation in a script as a new body value. Than you could try the following:

<transform>
    <groovy>
  request.body.label = exchange.getProperty('label');
  return request.body
 </groovy>
</transform>

Comment: I've made a couple changes in my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can help someone in the future:

As I know You can use standard Java approach with settters anf getters in body:

```
 .split(body())
      .setBody(simple("${body.setLogin('TEST')}"))
 .end()
```

It works inside `<split></split>`. Maybe inside another blocks.