# How can I set a Pojo Property from Route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, pojo

I have a route:

```
from("direct:test")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            RestResult result = new RestResult();
            exchange.getOut().setBody(result);
        }})
    ....
    .setBody(simple("${body.setStatusText('Some Status Text.')}"))
    .transform().body();
```

I set the body of the message with the class RestResult.
After that I do something and want to change one property StatusText in the Pojo. But if I do it like above, I get an Null-body. Because the return = null, overwrite the whole Body. But I only want to change the Property of my class into the body of the exchange.

```
public class RestResult {
    private String StatusText = "OK";
    public String   getStatusText() {                       return StatusText;}
    public void     setStatusText(String statusText) {      StatusText = statusText;}
}
```

Have someone an idea?

Comment: whay can't you use another processor to do so. `simple("${body.setStatusText('Some Status Text.')}"` returns null. Hence the body is null. You could  do `return this` from setStatusText method to solve this issue, but its not a gud idea. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404110/how-to-call-setter-method-on-body-in-a-camel-route

Comment: Unless you have to specifically use Camel's [Simple Language](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simple-language.html), please go ahead with a processor, like below.

````Java
.process(exchange -> {
  RestResult result = exchange.getIn().getBody(RestResult.class);

  if(result!=null){
     result.setStatusText("Some status text");
  }

  exchange.getIn().setBody(result);
  })
````

Comment: I think the route is better to read, when I only change one property else I write a processor.